# Katalon - How to receive Test Case as an argument in custom keyword?

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm trying to create a custom keyword that receives a Test Case as an argument and attemps to launch it for a given nummber of times.

I'm in a mixed team of technical and functional profiles for a test automation project using Katalon 5.10.1. I'm trying to create a custom keyword that receives a Test Case and a number of attempts so the given Test Case can be automatically retried in case of failure.

[image: What I already have]

This custom keyword receives the Test Case as an input String, but I want to be able to use the Test Case Browser just as WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase(wantedTestCase), [:], FailureHandling.OPTIONAL) does in Manual Mode so it is simpler for my coworkers to use.

I've noticed that an Object Repository Browser displays in Manual Mode when argument is of type TestObject, but it seems that the same does not happen when the type is TestCase yet CallTestCase keyword seems to be able to do so for the Test Cases folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to define it:

```
def up = CustomKeywords.'uploadFile.fileupload.listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories'(directory.toString())
```